# how to enroll dataset way in java

Tags: dataset, ckan

I am a java developer in Republic of korea
The data registered in ckan platform using java
it is difficult.
there no many information about java in ckan
I want RESTfull way to register the data.
I need help you
How to register the data using a Java method and using ckan api

I want to register data in a variety of ways and esay method
Please return to the relevant data and information

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/timrdf/CKANClient-J, it might give you a headstart.